# Greek characters in PDF with iText 7

Tags: java, fonts, character-encoding, itext, itext7

I am trying to create a pdf with greek characters using *iText 7* for Java.
Only latin characters and numbers are visible in the PDF.

I am loading fonts using this code:

```
PdfFont normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA, "CP1253");
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you embed the font? Pass a true in the PdfFontFactory#createFont() method after all the other arguments. Also, don't forget to use your font when creating text :)

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: You use Helvetica without embedding it. Helvetica is one of the standard 14 fornts which every PDF viewer is expected to know but merely with a limited character set, mostly Latin ones. Try using a font with Greek characters you have available as font file and are entitled to use for embedding

Comment: @mike_x_ what mkl said (Can't believe I looked over the actual font >.>), let's see, http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class, it's java but the relevant methods should be the same barring some capitals and replacing get/set with the property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
PdfFont normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
```

You can use any font that supports your language. Also Identity-H seems to be important as the encoding of the PDF file.

Comment: works and you can even use Font ce_langs_support_font = FontFactory.getFont(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN.name(), "Identity-H", true);    so that you are saved the pain of paths and use the Times Roman font built-into iText. The key here is the Identity-H encoding.